# Go - How to render the template to a temporary byte buffer using Pongo2?

Tags: go, html-email

I am trying to send HTML emails using Golang, but instead of using the native Golang html/template package I am trying to do it with [Pongo2](https://github.com/flosch/pongo2).

In this question: [Is it possible to create email templates with CSS in Google App Engine Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24093200/is-it-possible-to-create-email-templates-with-css-in-google-app-engine-go)

The user is providing this example, which is using the html/template

```
var tmpl = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("templates/email.html"))

buff := new(bytes.Buffer)
if err = tmpl.Execute(buff, struct{ Name string }{"Juliet"}); err != nil {
    panic(err.Error())
}
msg := &mail.Message{
    Sender:   "romeo@montague.com",
    To:       []string{"Juliet <juliet@capulet.org>"},
    Subject:  "See you tonight",
    Body:     "...you put here the non-HTML part...",
    HTMLBody: buff.String(),
}
c := appengine.NewContext(r)
if err := mail.Send(c, msg); err != nil {
    c.Errorf("Alas, my user, the email failed to sendeth: %v", err)
```

What I am trying to do

```
var tmpl = pongo2.Must(pongo2.FromFile("template.html"))
buff := new(bytes.Buffer)
tmpl.Execute(buff, pongo2.Context{"data": "best-data"}, w)
```

The problem here is that  pongo2.Execute() only allows to enter the context data and not the buff.

My end goal is to be able to write my templates using [Pongo2](https://github.com/flosch/pongo2), and I can render the HTML in a way where I can also use it for sending my emails.

My question is what I am doing it wrong? It's possible what I am trying to achieve? If I can find a way to render that HTML into a buff, I can use it later as part `buff.String()`, which will allow me to enter it in HTML body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ExecuteWriterUnbuffered`](https://godoc.org/github.com/flosch/pongo2#Template.ExecuteWriterUnbuffered) instead of `Execute`:

```
tmpl.ExecuteWriterUnbuffered(pongo2.Context{"data": "best-data"}, &buff)
```

Not sure what `w` is doing in your example. If it's another `Writer` that you'd like to write too, you can use an [io.MultiWriter](https://godoc.org/io#MultiWriter).

```
// writes to w2 will go to both buff and w
w2 := io.MultiWriter(&buff, w)
```